# Html Form Attachments Not Reaching Destination

Tags: php, base64, attachment, mime, mail-form

I have an html mail form on my site, which should allow users to attach an image file to their form submissions.

For a few years, the form had been working like a charm.

*Note: I have been directing the form data to a gmail account.

Recently, the form submissions began to be severely delayed in arriving, or never showed up at all.

I do not recall changing anything in the code that could have possibly caused this sudden change.

I have tested the issue by redirecting the form data to other email platforms, with 'partial' success.

More specifically... meaning that the form submissions do seem to arrive at the newly directed destination platforms  consistently when tested.

However... the attachments (images) do not successfully arrive. The attachments arrive broken (0 bytes) and cannot be downloaded or viewed on any of the other platforms.

This leads me to believe that the culprit may be somewhere in the file attachment part of the php code itself. This theory may explain why gmail rejects the submissions altogether, and why the other platform deliver the submissions, but with broken attachments.

However, as I mentioned, I have not altered the code in any way, and I have examined it several times, but I cannot spot any bugs or issues.

Any help in solving this mystery would be appreciated.

I have included my php-handler code below...

PHP HANDLER:

```
<?php

$fileName =  $_FILES['userImages']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['userImages']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_POST['userName'];
$email = $_POST['userEmail'];

$composition =

"\r\n\n\nName: "                        . $name .
"\r\nEmail Address: "                   . $email;

$fromname ="$name";
$fromemail = "$email";

$mailto = 'receiving@email.com';

$content = file_get_contents($tmpName);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$separator = md5(time());

$eol = "\r\n";

$headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
$body .= $composition . $eol;

$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $fileName . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
$body .= $content . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

@mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);

header('location: /sent_confirmation.php');

?>
```

Comment: You haven't shown the HTML form; for file attachments to work you need to make sure the form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: You should add some logging / debugging information to tell you if the uploads were successful (file size, etc). Then you can focus on where the real problem is which is probably in the mail transport. Getting PHP's `mail()` function right these days is a monumental task. I would highly recommend using a trusted SMTP service and something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit if the `<form>` wasn't right they'd get errors about array offsets on lines 3 and 4

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit Thank you so much for your comment. True, I did not include the form, but the form is quite basic, but yes... it does include enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit Thanks for pointing out the semicolon. That was just an error in my post. In the code on my site, the semicolon is there. I have changed it in the post now too.

Comment: Pls remove @ from mail() and also check the error log / mail log .

Comment: @Ken Lee: Thank you for the comment. I did remove the @ at your suggestion. Did not correct the broken attachment issue. Also, no new entries in error log.

Comment: Please try sending to a non-gmail.com address and see whether there is any difference. Let us know please

Comment: @KenLee Sorry for the delay. Yes... I have tested the form with different, non-gmail.com platforms/addresses, and the attachments arrive broken.  To clarify.... when I direct the form data to a gmail account, the form data only arrives about 1 out of every 10 attempts. But when it does arrive with gmail... the attachment (image) is intact and displayed. With all other platforms (non-gmail), the form data ALWAYS comes in, yet... the attachment (image) is broken.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing a number of `$eol` in your email content (especially in the attachment part)
2. You have not specified the $subject (e.g. $subject="Test email PHP";)

So please amend to :

```
<?php

$fileName =  $_FILES['userImages']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['userImages']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_POST['userName'];
$email = $_POST['userEmail'];


$subject="Test email PHP";


$composition ="\r\n\n\nName: " . $name . "\r\nEmail Address: ". $email;


$fromname =$name;
$fromemail = $email;

$mailto = 'receiving@email.com';

$content = file_get_contents($tmpName);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));



$separator = md5(uniqid(time()));

$eol = "\r\n";

$headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;". $eol. " boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
// $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol . $eol;

$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$body .= $composition . $eol;

$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;". $eol. " name=\"" . $fileName . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;

$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;". $eol . " filename=\"" . $fileName."\"" . $eol . $eol ; 
$body .= $content . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);

//header('location: /sent_confirmation.php');
echo "Done";

?>
```

By the way, please note that for xxx@gmail.com recipients, the gmail server may filter out your email because of various reasons (no PTR record / SPF / DMARC / DKIM, etc.) which you may have to fix separately. So please try the above for non-gmail account again first.